# Can I please know why this question is down-voted (and also voted to close)?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

[Question on Big Data algorithms](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/8882/what-are-some-good-big-data-algorithms)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, you can comment on the question rather than ask in Meta. Or flag it if you really think something is wrong and want a moderator to look.

It's not possible to know who downvoted or why. You can see the reason for the close vote: "Too Broad". This is indeed way too broad to make a good question on StackExchange. You're asking for a list of every big data algorithm.

Comment: Sean, Thank you for clarifying.  Yeah, that question might be a bit too broad.  _Deleted it_